# Blind TDOA Estimation

Tags: cross-correlation, matched-filter, time-of-arrival

I am not EE or DSP engineer, however I am working on a project that uses TDOA estimation for location finding. I am able to get the localization algorithm working using cross correlation to estimate TDOA.
The challenge is that the receivers are separated by a distance and I am trying to find a method where I wouldn't have to transfer the whole recorded signal (which is very large) . So the question is:

- Can I perform correlation using a smaller subset? or metadata on received signals?
- Can I use metadata or a parametric model of the received signal? So that I can transfer just the parameters or metadata -which would be much smaller in size- for TDOA estimation? What parameters or metadata would that be?
  Thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you just transmit time stamps?

Comment: For instance from GPS satellites?